# three.js: Are there methods for loading Line, Point, and Text data (and combinations)?

Tags: three.js

I'm attempting to migrate my [Coin3d geology visualization projects](http://www.beg.utexas.edu/resprog/3Dvis_seqstrat.php) over to Three.js.  I've experimented with the various loaders and have decided to use the JSON format & loader to load mesh data, but I cannot find a method for storing and loading lines, points, and text.  I tried the VRMLLoader, but the following code:

```
var vloader = new THREE.VRMLLoader();
vloader.load('line.wrl', function (geometry) {
  var line = new THREE.Line(geometry);
  scene.add( line );
});
```

returns nothing, which isn't surprising, given that IndexedLineSet is not referenced in VRMLLoader.js (IndexedFaceSet, Cylinder, Cone, etc are there).  The [JSON Geometry format 4](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Geometry-format-4) and Model Format 3 are mesh-centric if not mesh-exclusive, and I wonder if there are plans to add something like

```
"data":{
  "lines":[3,0,1,2,3...],
  "points":[0,2,4,1,3...]
}
```

to the spec?  In the meantime, does one of the other loaders support loading Lines, Points, and Text?  If not--and I assume the answer is no--is the best way to go about this to hack the JSONLoader to read

```
  "lines":[3,0,1,2,3...]   # or whatever I want to call it
```

and if so, how would one go about doing so?  In the loader callback, or would I have to make a custom my_JSONLoader.js?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on support for IndexedLineSet in the VrmlParser project. VrmlParser uses a ThreeJs renderer for display: http://github.com/bartmcleod/VrmlParser